# Permutation Game problem

Tags: permutations

could you help me to understand this problem?

This is the problem statement

Alice and Bob are playing a game called "The Permutation Game". The game is parameterized with the int N. At the start of the game, Alice chooses a positive integer x, and Bob chooses a permutation of the first Npositive integers. Let p be Bob's permutation. Alice will start at 1, and apply the permutation to this value x times. More formally, let f(1) = p[1], and f(m) = p[f(m-1)] for all m >= 2. Alice's final value will be f(x). Alice wants to choose the smallest x such that f(x) = 1 for any permutation Bob can provide. Compute and return the value of such x modulo 1,000,000,007.

for N= 3 I found that we obtain this table:

**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>1,2,3</th>
    <th>1,3,2</th>
    <th>2,1,3</th>
    <th>2,3,1</th>
    <th>3,1,2</th>
    <th>3,2,1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>f(1)</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>f(2)</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>f(3)</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>f(4)</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>f(5)</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>f(6)</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**

but I don't know why we got this values

could somebody explain why we get this values for N = 3

Comment: It's hard to really answer without understanding what your particular confusion is about, but the short version is that what you're looking for is the least common multiple of the possible _orders_ of all elements in a _permutation group_.

Comment: but how can I get the values of the table in a piece of paper I am trying to understand the specific case when N= 3

Answer (score 0):

Take the third line of the tables.  The permutation, in the first table, is 2,1,3.  That means: Replace 1 by 2; Replace 2 by 1; Replace 3 by 3. So you are swapping 1 and 2 at each stage.
$f(1)=p(1)=2, f(2)=p(f(1))=p(2)=1,f(3)=p(f(2))=p(1)=2$.  In this permutation, you are stepping back and forth; f(odd numbers)=2, f(even numbers)=1.
Is this a Project Euler question?

Comment: No is from topcoder, how it work for the last 2 lines?